# Деплой web-приложения без доступа в интернет

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js

Написал небольшое приложение на nuxt.js (c блэкджеком и mongoDB) для своей маленькой корпоративной сети из 15 машин и тут до меня доходит, что мой знания по деплою == 0, подскажите с чего начать и куда идти. Гугл подсказывает про разворачивания приложения на Heroku и прочее, но у меня голый сервак так сказать "on-premise" с windows server 2012 и без выхода в инет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ссылка на подобный [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489956/how-could-others-on-a-local-network-access-my-nodejs-app-while-its-running-on).

Да ничего сложного нет, запускаете ваше готовое приложение на сервере для этого вам нужно установить `node.js`, mongoDB и приложение, как бы вы разрабатываете на сервере. Единственное там где у вас `localhost` устанавливаете IP адрес сервера будет что-то на подобии http://your.network.ip.address:port/ т.е. http://192.168.0.3:3000. Всем из сети будет доступен ваш сайт по данному адресу. Это не обязательно быть сервером можете поднять для начала на своей машине.

Comment: Спасибо большое, разобрался

Comment: Не за что рад помочь